# Change date and time format

Tags: settings

Is there a way to customize the date time format in the top task bar? Cannot locate the settings with dconf-editor.

Answer (score 0):

The Date & Time panel in the System Settings app will let you change between 12 hour and 24 hour time format and show or hide the date, day of the week and seconds. If that is all you need.